# Designing iPhone/iPad apps for testability

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, design-patterns, ipad

I'm currently using [GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) and [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) for testing my app. I'm using them because I like the fact that I can run test code on the actual device.

The way my app is currently designed is that I have some central services and objects available through properties on the app delegate. For example, I've centralised some core data functionality which can be accessed by `[UIApplication sharedApplication].coreData`.

The problem I've encountered is that in order to run unit tests on the device or simulator, GHUnit uses it's own app delegate which doesn't have these properties. So if a unit triggers code which wants to access them, it fails.

So I'm looking at the design of the app and wondering if I should redesign the way these core facilities are made available. How do you guys design your apps?

One thing I'm considering is extracting this functionality out to a separate object so that I can then use OCMock to simulate it for testing purposes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this a while I realised there was a simpler solution. I created a category with the app delegate's interface which applies to the GU Unit app delegate used when running the tests. This way I can get the tests to run and use this category to return OC Mocks when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

And another technique. This time I extended the GH Unit test iPhone app delegate and added the methods and properties I needed. I then modified the main class to call that instead of the original.

Ahhh, so many ways to achieve the same result :-)